# How to pass environment variable received from GitHub actions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

In my [action.yml](https://github.com/paramt/github-actions-playground/blob/master/action.yml) I defined an input:

```
name: 'test action'
author: Param Thakkar
description: 'test'

inputs: 
  test_var:
    description: 'A test variable'
    required: true

runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
```

And in my workflow I passed the test_var:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Test the GH action
    uses: paramt/github-actions-playground@master
    with:
      test_var: "this is just a test"
```

So there should be an environment variable that's created when the workflow runs, right? But when I run this short python script:

```
import os

print(os.getenv('TEST_VAR'))
print("It works!")

exit(0)
```

It prints:

```
None
It works!
```

I think that I have to pass the ENV variable through my Dockerfile... Right now my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:latest

# Add files to the image
ADD entrypoint.py /entrypoint.py
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

# Save ENV var in a temp file
RUN $TEST_VAR > /temp_var

# Install dependencies and make script executable
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.py

RUN echo "temp var: "
RUN cat /temp_var

# Run script with the ENV var
ENTRYPOINT export TEST_VAR="$TEST_VAR"; /entrypoint.py
```

But the variable isn't echoed and isn't passed to the pythons script either.. am I missing something? When I tried to set my `$TEMP_VAR` to a random piece of string, it *is* sent through to the Python script. Is this a mistake on my behalf or is the GitHub action not working as intended?

Here's [the link to the test repo](https://github.com/paramt/github-actions-playground)

Comment: How were you able to access your input arg defined in action.yml inside your Dockerfile? I'm trying to do the same and I'm having some trouble with that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are trying to read the wrong environment variable name. GitHub Actions adds `INPUT_` to the name of the input variable. So try the following:

```
print(os.getenv('INPUT_TEST_VAR'))
```

From the documentation:

> When you specify an input to an action in a workflow file or use a
>   default input value, GitHub creates an environment variable for the
>   input with the name INPUT_. The environment variable
>   created converts input names to uppercase letters and replaces spaces
>   with _ characters.
>
> For example, if a workflow defined the numOctocats and octocatEyeColor
>   inputs, the action code could read the values of the inputs using the
>   INPUT_NUMOCTOCATS and INPUT_OCTOCATEYECOLOR environment variables.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputs

Answer (score 9):

A bit late but for the next one, you can also use the `env` field :

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Test the GH action
    uses: paramt/github-actions-playground@master
    env:
      test_var: "this is just a test"
```

which will be included during the creation of your docker and pass without the prefix `INPUT_`

Comment: does that make it available inside the container or does that require another step?

Answer (score 5):

Keep env vars secret by specifying them in `Settings -> Secrets` in the repo, and then calling them in the workflow:

For example, consider a workflow that runs an `R` script followed by a `Python` script. First, in `.github/workflows/my_job.yml` notice the `MY_VAR` variable, which points to a stored secret with `${{ secrets.MY_VAR}}`. The rest is standard code (run on cron, specify Ubuntu OS and Docker image, define workflow steps).

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 17 * * *'
jobs:
  my_job:
    name: my job
    env:
      MY_VAR: ${{ secrets.MY_VAR }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    container:
     image: docker.io/my_username/my_image:my_tag
    steps:
      - name: checkout_repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: run some code
        run: bash ./src/run.sh
```

Next, in the scripts that compose your workflow, you can access the env var specified in the workflow file above as you would locally.

For example, in the repo, let's assume `src/run.sh` calls an `R` script followed by a `Python` script.

In `R` access the env var and store as an object:

```
my_var <- Sys.getenv("MY_VAR")

.
.
.
```

In `Python` access the env var and store as an object:

```
import os

my_var = os.getenv("MY_VAR")
.
.
.
```

See the [docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables).

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: This approach is not secure. I was using it on a dummy-dev project. See explanation from Sun (in the reply) and check Peter Evan's answer**

However, in my case, none of the answers worked. Here's how I fixed it.

```html
---
name: Build and Push Docker Image to AWS ECR
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  FOO: '${{ secrets.FOO }}'

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    name: Build Project and Push to AWS ECR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
        ... 
        
      - name: Build and Push to AWS ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        run: |
          docker build --build-arg FOO=$FOO -t $ECR_REGISTRY/crew-charge-app:latest .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/crew-charge-app:latest
```

I first had to get the FOO variable from github secrets using ${{secrets.FOO}} then pass it onto the docker file using docker build --build-arg FOO=$FOO --build-arg BAR=$BAR -t .

Then inside the docker file I had to declare both as an ARG and ENV to be available at all times.

```html
FROM node:14

ARG FOO=${FOO}

ENV FOO=${FOO}

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN yarn install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN FOO=$FOO yarn build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["yarn", "start" ]
```

Important part was to RUN FOO=$FOO yarn build because setting the ENV alone doesn't pass it onto the container.

Comment: Never do this. this is insecure in the case where FOO supposed to be secret value

--build-arg FOO=$FOO means you will be able to see the cached secret when any user who has access to image can run the command

docker history <imagename>

Comment: I presume this is perfectly safe in cases where FOO is not an important value?