# How to use github token in Dockerfile that is built in GitHub Actions and trying to clone private repository?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

Here's my GitHub Action step. `PRIVATE_REQUIREMENT_OWNER_TOKEN` secret is already created and contains GitHub token with full `repo` scope:

```
  - name: Build docker image
    id: docker_build
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      push: false
      context: .
      tags: 'username/image:latest'
      secrets: |
        "github_token=${{ secrets.PRIVATE_REQUIREMENT_OWNER_TOKEN }}"
```

Here's a line in requirements.txt that contains a link to the private repository and trying to be installed while building a docker image from Dockerfile during the step above:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/username/private-repository
```

The line has been added to the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_token pip install https://$(cat /run/secrets/github_token)@github.com/username/private-repository.git
```

that throws following error in GitHub Actions:

```
#11 [ 6/12] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=PRIVATE_REQUIREMENT_OWNER_TOKEN_SECRET pip install https://$(cat /run/secrets/PRIVATE_REQUIREMENT_OWNER_TOKEN_SECRET)@github.com/username/private-repository.git
#11 sha256:b3d88dd9813db3257b15f53f1eb5a4c593c69ff98ec03cc4d70d564df1a1f7f6
#11 0.697 Collecting https://****@github.com/vassilyvv/django-sinbad.git
#11 0.790   ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting https://****@github.com/username/private-repository
.git
#11 0.791 ERROR: Could not install requirement https://****@github.com/username/private-repository
.git because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://github.com/username/private-repository
 for URL https://****@github.com/username/private-repository.git
```

But when I'm trying to use the same token to clone a repository on the local machine, it goes well:

```
git clone https://<token>@github.com/username/private-repository.git
```

I completely have no idea how to use this `github_token` to successfully clone the private repository mentioned above.

My goal is to clone the private GitHub repository while building a docker image from Dockerfile in GitHub Actions. And I almost sure that I already performed some wrong steps. Please help!

Comment: Hi. This thread might help you: [Pass variable from a github action to docker image build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814953/pass-variable-from-github-action-to-docker-image-build)

Comment: @Vas Is the `/run/secrets/github_token` base64 encoded, or does it actually include the expected value?

Comment: It was entered into the secrets section without encoding. I'm not sure how it's storing in `/run/secrets/github_token` since I didn't manage to display it in GH Actions logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see this as a problem with the git URL provided to `pip`. If you need to install a python package from a private git repository, you may use the following format.

`pip install git+https://<PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/username/private-repo.git`

So in your case, it will be:

```
pip install git+https://$(cat /run/secrets/github_token)@github.com/username/private-repository.git
```

See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#git

Comment: You're awesome!