# How can I pass an environment variable to a Docker Container Github Action

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions, continuous-deployment

Is it possible to pass an environment variable to a custom GitHub action that runs a docker container?

For example, I have the following custom GitHub action below:

```
name: "Build Firmware"
description: "Build Firmware"
inputs:
  target:
    description: 'Target to build'
    required: true
    default: ''
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
```

And then I have a GitHub workflow that uses the above custom action

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build Firmware
        uses: ./docker/autobuild
        env:
          target: 'test'
```

As you can see I try to pass the environment variable called target, but when trying to use it in the Dockerfile like so:

```
ENV TARGET_ENV $TARGET
```

It doesn't seem to actually pass the environment variable (blank variable). Am I doing something wrong? I need to specify a target for this job so it can be used in the docker container.

Comment: Did you try following the solutions suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242357/how-to-pass-environment-variable-received-from-github-actions) ?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I have, I tried seeing if the variable was INPUT_TARGET but not at all, even tried using the GitHub Secrets to see if those worked, but nope. Looked at a lot of StackOverflow threads so am a bit clueless. Configuration in this thread remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `options` parameter to pass your arguments.

Digging into the original code we can see that the image is run via:

```bash
exec docker run -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" $INPUT_OPTIONS --entrypoint=$INPUT_SHELL $INPUT_IMAGE -c "`cat semicolon_delimited_script`"
```

Notice the `$INPUT_OPTIONS`

I prefer to create a file a pass it like such:

```yaml
uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
with:
  image: zarco/dagster:latest
  options: "--env-file test.env"
  run: <your-script>
```

You will be able to expose your environment variables like this into the docker container.